# Ubuntu 22.04 iso not downloading

Tags: 22.04, iso, downloads

I've tried numerous times to download the Ubuntu 22.04 iso file to both a Ubuntu 22.04 desktop and to a windows 10 notebook. The download begins normally but partway through it stops with the following message: "ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso   failed". I started the download from https://releases.ubuntu.com/22.04/ by clicking on the "64-bit PC (AMD64) desktop image" link. Am I missing something?

Comment: It looks like your internet is bad. If that is the case try again tomorrow. Try from some other place with better Internet. Try a mirror location in your country or close to your location.

Answer (score 11):

Try downloading with torrent. There the download would not fail even if the internet is bad.

https://releases.ubuntu.com/22.04/ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent

Comment: The BitTorrent protocol also has the added benefit of verifying the integrity of downloads. So if you download Ubuntu using the official torrent seed, you can be certain that the ISO is not corrupted

Comment: To explain why that works: BitTorrent essentially breaks up your download into lots and lots of tiny downloads. Even if one individual download fails, that can just be re-tried. So eventually, you will end up with a complete download.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using another mirror

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors

ps:  When I use another mirror, I tend to verify the checksum still by downloading it from the main site and checking that.. but normal verify of ISO should be sufficient (ie. https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0)

Comment: Thank you. This worked great. Used the Univ of MN mirror.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be alleviated by using a download manager which can resume interrupted downloads. `wget` or `axel` etc. are some command line tools available on linux.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try with:

```
wget https://releases.ubuntu.com/22.04/ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
```

or maybe this on Windows:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://releases.ubuntu.com/22.04/ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
```